# Relay Error when deleting: RelayMutationQuery: Invalid field name on fat query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs

I'm running into an issue when I attempt to commit a deletion mutation. When I commit, I get the error `` Uncaught Invariant Violation: RelayMutationQuery: Invalid field name on fat query, `company`. ``. Viewing, creating and updating nodes all work. For some reason I just can't delete. It mentions the company field in the fatQuery, but the only field I have in the fat query is the deletedUserId I get back from the server. Thanks in advance!

Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import DeleteUserMutation from 'mutations/DeleteUserMutation';
import styles from './EmployeeItem.css';

class EmployeeItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={styles.employee}>
        <p><strong>ID:</strong> {user.id}</p>
        <p><strong>First Name:</strong> {user.firstName}</p>
        <p><strong>Last Name:</strong> {user.lastName}</p>
        <p><strong>Email:</strong> {user.email}</p>
        <div className="btn-group">
          <Link to={`/company/employees/${user.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">View Employee</Link>
          <button onClick={this.handleRemove} className="btn btn-danger">Delete User</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  handleRemove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {user, company} = this.props;

    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new DeleteUserMutation({user, company}));
  };
}

export default Relay.createContainer(EmployeeItem, {
  fragments: {
    company: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Company {
        id
        ${DeleteUserMutation.getFragment('company')}
      }
    `,
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        email
        ${DeleteUserMutation.getFragment('user')}
      }
    `
  }
});
```

Mutation:

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class DeleteUserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    company: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Company {
        id
      }
    `,
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id
      }
    `
  };

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {deleteUser}`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteUserPayload {
        deletedUserId
      }
    `;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.user.id,
    }
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'NODE_DELETE',
      parentName: 'company',
      parentID: this.props.company.id,
      connectionName: 'employees',
      deletedIDFieldName: 'deletedUserId'
    }]
  }

  // Wasn't sure if this was causing the error but it appears to be 
  // something else.
  // getOptimisticResponse() {
  //   return {
  //     deletedUserId: this.props.user.id
  //   }
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is referring to the fact that you reference the "company" in your `getConfigs()` implementation. The `NODE_DELETE` config tells Relay how to construct the mutation query by mapping nodes in the store (e.g. `parentID`) to fields on the fat query (e.g. `parentName`).

Although you might not necessarily need it today, you should add the `company` to the mutation payload & fat query here, since the company *is* being affected by this change. More specifically, the company's employees connection is being modified :)

Comment: This solved my issue. I added a globalId to the root field (in my case an object called "verify") and I also changed my mutation on the server to return an edge, rather than just the underlying type. I also added the root "verify" object to the mutation output fields: it would make sense that the client's relay mutation needs that to know which object owns the connection, where to put the new edge.

Answer (score 1):

NevilleS' solution solved it for me:

I added a globalId to the root field (in my case an object called "verify") and I also changed my mutation on the server to return an edge, rather than just the underlying type. I also added the root "verify" object to the mutation output fields: it would make sense that the client's relay mutation needs that to know which object owns the connection, where to put the new edge.

```
export const Verify = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Verify',
fields: () => ({
  id: globalIdField('Verify'),
  verifications: {
    args: connectionArgs,
    type: VerificationConnection,
    resolve: (rootValue, args) => connectionFromArray(rootValue.verifications, args)
  },
```

Adding "verify" and "verificationEdge" to the mutation's output fields.

```
export const AddVerifiedSchool = mutationWithClientMutationId({
name: 'AddVerifiedSchool',
inputFields: {
  verification: {
    type: VerifiedSchoolInput
  }
},
outputFields: {
  success: {
    type: GraphQLBoolean,
    resolve: () => true
  },
  verificationEdge: {
    type: VerificationEdge,
    resolve: ({verification, context}) => {
      console.log('verification', verification);
      return verification
    }
  },
  verify: {
    type: Verify,
    resolve: ({verification, context}) => {
      return context.rootValue
    }
  }
},
```

Adding the verify field to the fat query, and (the globalId "id" from verify) to the fragments, and using the new globalId to identify the node where the connection exists.

```
static fragments = {
  verify: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Verify { id }`,
  action: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Action { name url }`
};

getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'RANGE_ADD',
    parentName: 'verify',
    parentID: this.props.verify.id,
    connectionName: 'verifications',
    edgeName: 'verificationEdge',
    rangeBehaviors: {
      '': 'append'
    }
  }];
}

getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
  fragment on AddVerifiedSchoolPayload {
    verification {
      ${VerifiedSchool.getFragment('verification')}
    }
    verify {
      id
    }
  }`
}
```