# Using NODE_DELETE without refetching data

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

Using a `NODE_DELETE` requires the parent, and to actually return the parent of the connection:

[Relay Error when deleting: RelayMutationQuery: Invalid field name on fat query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165693/relay-error-when-deleting-relaymutationquery-invalid-field-name-on-fat-query)

Unfortunately, using this refetches **ALL** my nested items, which is simply unacceptable for my use case.

```
  fragment on deleteItemNested @relay(pattern: true) {
    id
    ok
    item {
      nested {
        edges {
          node { id }
        }
      }
    }
    clientMutationId
  }
```

Is there a way to delete an item from a connection/list without refetching all data? Trying not to fetch for the edges in nested results in nested being just an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the nested items are refetched because `@relay(pattern: true)` was used in the query. This makes the query to match against the tracked query, which already includes the nested fields. See an excellent answer by [steveluscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802047/steveluscher) to the question [Purpose of @relay(pattern:true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103296/purpose-of-relaypatterntrue).

The code example of `NODE_DELETE` in [mutation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html) is worth taking a look.